# How to implement a list of dropboxes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on a C# project using ASP.NET. And I'd like to implement a list of dropboxes. So a User starts with a dropbox and can select a method and next to the dropbox is a + and - button, which enables a user to add more dropboxes. So I am wondering how can I implement that is it possible to build a List of dropboxes in ASP.NET?

Comment: Hi, Senna...could you give some specific examples, or at least things you have already tried?

Comment: The thing is I have nothing because I don't have an idea how to implement it...I need the idea pls. Currently I have implemented it with radiobuttons, a user can click a radio button and the dropbox is enabled, but it should be modular and the user should be able to use multiple methods in different orders.

Comment: which means: dropbox (contains all methods) + button and - button

Comment: Please rephrase your query in more details.

Comment: Ok you have an ASP .NET website: First I start with a textbox where someone can add a text. Below a dropdown box which contains methods that you can perform on the text. But I want to perform multiple methods on the text in different orders, there for after the drop box there is a + button, where I can automatically add another dropdown box and select another method.

Comment: Do you want to add the dropdown list records on clicking the + button and the record is in textbox. and you want to delete the dropdown item on clicking the - button

Comment: If I click the + button another dropbox is enabled/visible and I can select the same methods from the first dropdown box. If I click the - button next to the dropbox the whole dropbox is disabled/not visible any more. It has nothing to do with the items in the dropbox itself.

Comment: Can I associate the dropbox with dropdownlist? What are these methods? How are you relating the method with dropbox?

Comment: the items you can select in the dropdownbox are methods that you can perform on the text. yes sorry dropbox and dropdownlist is the same here in the context yes.

Comment: Why the requirement is seems so confidential? It seems to be coming out in installments? Will you like to brief m,ore if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any server side code for this, client side scripting is ideal solution for your needs.

Having such HTML:

```html
<div id="MainPlaceholder">
    <div id="DropDownPlaceholder">
        <select name="myDropDown">
            <option value="1">First</option>
            <option value="2">Second</option>
            <option value="3">Third</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="AddDropDown(this);">+</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="RemoveDropDown(this);">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need the following pure JavaScript to make it work:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
var added_counter = 0;

function AddDropDown(sender) {
    var parent = sender.parentNode;

    //make fresh clone:
    var oClone = parent.cloneNode(true);

    //append to main placeholder:
    parent.parentNode.appendChild(oClone);

    //store change in global variable:
    added_counter++;
}

function RemoveDropDown(sender) {
    //don't allow to remove when there is only one left
    if (added_counter <= 0) {
        alert("One drop down must exist");
        return;
    }

    var parent = sender.parentNode;

    //disable so value won't be passed when form submitted:
    parent.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].disabled = true;

    //hide:
    parent.style.display = "none";

    //store change in global variable:
    added_counter--;    
}
</script>
```

The code has comments, but if you need any further explanation please feel free to ask.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/PmVJm/).

**Edit**: As you need to read the selected values on the server side code, better approach would be to change the name of each cloned drop down:

```
var totalAddedCounter = 0;

function AddDropDown(sender) {
    var parent = sender.parentNode;

    //make fresh clone:
    var oClone = parent.cloneNode(true);

    //assign unique name:
    oClone.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].name += "_" + totalAddedCounter;

    //append to main placeholder:
    parent.parentNode.appendChild(oClone);

    //store change in global variable:
    added_counter++;
    totalAddedCounter++;
}
```

Now the tricky part is reading those values. Instead of plain `dropboxlistID.Text` you will have to iterate over all posted values looking for what you need:

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("dropboxlistID"))
    {
        string text = Request.Form[key];
        //.....
    }
```

Comment: But one question came up, while I tried to add this in my code. I am using asp.net and I am using a DropDownList which is embedded in a table. So what do I've to be aware of?

Comment: <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>Methods:</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="methodSelector" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="233px" />
                <button type="addButton" OnClick="AddDropDown(this);">+</button>
                <button type="deleteButton"OnClick="RemoveDropDown(this);">-</button>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>

Comment: @senna this should cause additional table cells to be added to the same table row. What problem you have?

Comment: It doesn't add a new dropbox, it just pumps up for seconds and goes away immdiatly

Comment: @senna try wrapping with additional placeholder: `<asp:TableCell><div><asp:DropDownList ID="methodSelector" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="233px" /> <button type="addButton" OnClick="AddDropDown(this);">+</button> <button type="deleteButton"OnClick="RemoveDropDown(this);">-</button></div></asp:TableCell>` - any change?

Comment: still same behaviour. it just pumps up and goes away.

Comment: no I don't get an error but the new dropdown element with it's buttons is shortly visible and goes immediatly away!

Comment: fixed bug. changed the type to "button" instead of addButton and deleteButton. Now it's working. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @senna OMG silly me! Totally missed that. It caused the button to be submit button meaning clicking it caused the form to get submitted. I'm getting old, I guess.

Comment: Shadow could you help out with that too pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106513/how-to-get-the-order-of-dynamically-created-dropdownlists?