# How to get the order of dynamically created DropDownLists

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've created some drop down lists using JavaScript, ASP.NET.

A user can add as many drop down lists as he wants by clicking a "+" button and removing them by clicking a "-" button.

If it's hard to understand what I mean pls see " [How to implement a list of dropboxes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101262/how-to-implement-a-list-of-dropboxes-in-c-sharp) ".

And now I'd like to implement the code behind and want to define the order of the drop down lists, but I don't know which one is my first drop down list, etc.

We assume that all `<asp:DropDownList>` contain the following for list elements: method1, method2, method3 and method4. If a user selects an element, a method in the codebehind is implemented.

Example:
dropboxlist1: select list item method2,
dropboxlist2: select list item method1,
dropboxlist3: select list item method3,

```
string txt= "";
if (dropboxlistID.Text == "method1"){
  txt = method1Imp();
} else if (dropboxlistID.Text == "method2") {
  txt = method2Imp();
} else if (dropboxlistID.Text == "method3") {
  txt = method3Imp();
} else {
}
```

But at this moment I don't have any idea which drop down lists came first and which method should be performed on my string first.

Answer (score 2):

Try enqueueing each method into a queue as a delegate, then draining (invoking each delegate) the queue once you're ready from a single thread. This will ensure that the order of execution matches the order of user choices.

Sorry I didn't initally include code. Here's a basic example to get you started:

```
Queue<Func<string>> actions = new Queue<Func<string>>();
if(dropboxListID.Text =="m1")
{
 actions.Enqueue(method1Imp);
}
if(dropboxListID.Text = "m2")
{
 action.Enqueue(method2Imp);
}

...
Sometime Later when you're ready to process these
...
string txt = "";    
while(actions.Count >0)
{
 var method = actions.Dequeue();
 txt = method();
}
```

Here's a blog post that delves further into the concept of a work/task queue:

http://yacsharpblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/simple-task-queue.html

Comment: Could you possibly improve this answer by showing some example code to get the OP started?

Comment: Very nice, +1 from me.  Thanks for adding an example.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your drop down lists will be contained in a parent.

Let us say (acc to your link) your parent is DropDownPlaceholder.

```
<div id="DropDownPlaceholder">
```

Use linq to get all children of it. Cast them as drop down lists and then your can loop on them to find your matter.

Comment: this wouldn't work because my refined code looks like the following:               <asp:TableCell>  
                        <div>  
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="methodSelector" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="233px" />
                        <button type="button" onClick="AddDropDown(this);">+</button>
                        <button type="button" onClick="RemoveDropDown(this);">-</button>
                        </div>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

Answer (score 0):

To get the order of dropdownlists:

1. First set the IDs/ClientIDs of hard-coded dropdownlists in *aspx page* and
   count them (say 2 dropdownlists are present)
2. While creating dropdownlists dynamically, append a count integer at
   the end of their IDs/ClientIDs like ddl3, ddl4 (start the count from 3)
3. Then in your code, you can find the dropdownlist of selected element:

   ```
   if (ddl.ClientID.EndsWith("1")){
     // 1st ddl
   } else if (ddl.ClientID.EndsWith("2")) {
     // 2nd ddl
   } else if (ddl.ClientID.EndsWith("3")) {
     // 3rd ddl
   }
   ...
   ```